# Referencing jar file of google play service in map v2 project

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm trying to reference the jar file of google-play-service-lib but each time i reference it from the properties window, it gives me a red cross beside the lib. 
I tried uninstalling the google play service from the SDK service and re-installing it again.. also it didn't work up.

okay now i've changed the path of importing to the same drive where i keep my projects and thx god it worked... 
but now the maps open with a white blank page.

and what was written in the logcat : 
Unable to load google maps

can u please help me solving this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**import “google-play-services_lib”.**
Select File-->Import
Select Android-->Existing Android Code into Workspace
Browse and select \sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject
Select “google-play-services_lib” and finish.

for detailed steps have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: I've tried this, but Eclipse says it cannot write the `.project` file in the indicated `google-play-services_lib` directory. Obviously, the immediate reason is that Eclipse cannot write in the Program Files directory, where the SDK is located, but the more concrete question would be why modifying the `.project` file (that apparently belongs to the SDK and thus should be "correct") is necessary in the first place.

Comment: i had import int this way but it's give me error in values folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the workspace path, the library of google play service must be copied to your workspace not in another path.