# Can't setup Google play service library for Google Drive in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api

I want to integrate Google Drive api in my app. I follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) to setup an example and [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to setup Google Play Service library. The problem is when I link  Google play service library to my project, I got these issues:

- `@integer/google_play_services_version` not found. I searched and tried many ways but doesn't help (for example, [Adding Google Play services version to your app's manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest) and [Google Play Services Library update and missing symbol @integer/google_play_services_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv)). Then I find out **there is no `version.xml` in original google play library**, even though I update the latest library in Android SDK Manager.
- Can't import any Drive packages in my Drive example project. It looks like this:
     `The import com.google.android.gms.common.api cannot be resolved`

Here is my detail:
[image]

[image]
[image]
Does anyone know these problems?

Comment: you need to add `google_play_services` version as `<meta-data>` tag under your `<application>` tag in `manifest.xml` file

Comment: @SimplePlan I already added it. You can see in my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `Manifest.xml` add this tag within `<application>` tag

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: @R4j have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your library project?

Comment: @R4j do you have the latest version of play services LIB? if not update to latest version. and re-import the library project (If you already updated).

Comment: I have latest play service lib. I updated it before importing to my workspace. The problem is the original library don't have `version.xml` file and I don't know why

Comment: then paste this `version.xml` in your library project;s `values folder` http://www31.speedyshare.com/Hm3SK/download/version.xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49199/discussion-between-nitin-misra-and-r4j)

Comment: After I reinstall Google play service lib, it worked well. Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bit of info here: https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-gdaa (see readme.txt, point 4c). You may find some info bits useful. The easiest HACK is to just stick version number from "version.xml" (like 4132500 for libver 14) in your manifest.