# Mapview crashed in android api v2

Tags: android

I tried to create a mapview using android api v2. But my app got crashed in device. But working in emulator not crashing

These are the main errors i got. I cant figure out whats the problem. Please help me. 
I used tutorial from androidhive.

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samplemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <permission
        android:name="com.example.samplemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.samplemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.samplemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD1F0YSlV2_WqlY9yhJpqfsPP2jrtod_TU" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_main**

<

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.samplemap;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

On clicking play service on emulator(google map api v2 wont work in emulator ), I get the following errors:

```
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-17 16:47:47.711: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have not declared correctly the version number in your manifest. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest

Comment: What is your `minSDKversion` ?

Comment: Minimum 12 maximum 17

Comment: You have removed the crash error from your question, which is cruical to solving your problem and which, again, is due to a bad setup of google play services

Answer (score 2):

Your logcat clearly said

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:
>      
>   04-17 14:59:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): 
>    Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following
>   declaration within the  element:

Try to add `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml` file like

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Make your `manifest.xml` like this

```
....<application>
..............
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="Key" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: It is not crashing in emulator, but when I convert to apk and in device it got crashed.