# Google Maps API v2 - Fragment's error

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-maps, android-fragments

I know that this question maybe was asked several times, but trust me, i tried every possibility and it doesn't work. I will be as briefly as possible.

**.java**

```
package com.example.aa_lbs;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

/**
 * Demonstrate the use of GPS within Android. Google Maps is optional for this
 * application, but is useful in visualizing the output. Google Maps does not
 * run in the AVD.
 * 
 * @author Alex Tushinsky (alext@ltmod.com)
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class LBSActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager oLoc;
    private Location currentLoc;
    private Location previousLoc;

    private double totalDistance = 0;
    private long eventStartTime = 0;

    TextView txtOutput = null;

    private GoogleMap oMap;
    Marker oMark = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lbs);

        // Criteria object is optional. Will return value representing "GPS"
        Criteria oGPSSettings = new Criteria();
        oGPSSettings.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        oGPSSettings.setSpeedRequired(true);
        oGPSSettings.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        oGPSSettings.setBearingRequired(false);
        oGPSSettings.setCostAllowed(false);
        oGPSSettings.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);

        txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);

        oLoc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String provider = oLoc.getBestProvider(oGPSSettings, true);

        if (provider != null) {
            oLoc.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, this);
            // or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER instead of provider variable
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }

        eventStartTime = getRawTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLoc = location;
        long currentTime = getRawTime();
        if (previousLoc != null) {
            // Calculates the distance between the last location and the
            // current.
            double dis = getDistance(previousLoc, currentLoc);
            // Adds the distance to the previous total.
            totalDistance += dis; // in KM
            long totalTimeDiff = (currentTime - eventStartTime) / 1000L;
            double CurrentMetersPerSecond = location.getSpeed();
            double kps = totalTimeDiff / totalDistance; // km per second
            // 1 kilometer per second = 3600 kilometers per hour or kps / 60
            // minutes / 60 seconds
            double kPH = 1 / ((kps / 60) / 60);

            String sText = "Distance: "
                    + String.format("%.2f", Double.valueOf(totalDistance))
                    + " km\n" + "Speed: "
                    + String.format("%.2f", (CurrentMetersPerSecond * 3.6))
                    + " kph\n" + "Avg Speed: " + String.format("%.2f", (kPH))
                    + " kph\n" + "Lon: " + currentLoc.getLongitude() + "\n"
                    + "Lat: " + currentLoc.getLatitude() + "\n" + "Alt: "
                    + currentLoc.getAltitude();

            txtOutput.setText(sText);

        }

        // sets this location as last location.
        previousLoc = currentLoc;

        LatLng oPos = new LatLng(currentLoc.getLatitude(),
                currentLoc.getLongitude());

        oMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (oMap != null) {
            oMap.clear(); // otherwise old markers remain

            oMark = oMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(oPos).title(
                    "My Location"));

            oMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(oPos, 17));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        oLoc.removeUpdates(this);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), provider + " is disabled.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        oLoc.removeUpdates(this);
        oLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), provider + " is enabled.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        oLoc.removeUpdates(this);
        oLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        oLoc.removeUpdates(this);
        oLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        oLoc.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Returns the current date/time in milliseconds since epoch.
     */
    public static long getRawTime() {
        Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance();
        return dt.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    /**
     * getDistance is used to return the distance in kilometers between two
     * location points.
     */
    public static double getDistance(Location PreviousLocation,
            Location CurrentLocation) { // in KM

        double lat1 = PreviousLocation.getLatitude();
        double lon1 = PreviousLocation.getLongitude();
        double lat2 = CurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        double lon2 = CurrentLocation.getLongitude();

        double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
        double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);

        double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math
                .cos(lonB - lonA)) + (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
        double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
        double dist = ang * 6371; // earth's radius!
        return dist;
    }

}
```

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOutput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aa_lbs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.aa_lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.aa_lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.aa_lbs.LBSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDR3gdB6hail53aWqO9CCaU1Mz3L3719_Y" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Virtual Machine**

[image]

The Error:

```
04-18 11:04:20.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aa_lbs/com.example.aa_lbs.LBSActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
```

My app crash when it starts. I know the problem is with the fragments, but i don't find it! PLEASE! Help me, I give up...I'd appreciate forever.

Thank you so much.

Comment: you have to add `<meta-data>` tag  with `google_play_services_version` under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml file` for this go to [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129473/mapview-crashed-in-android-api-v2/23129535#23129535). just guess and better to try in _REAL PHYSICAL DEVICE_

Comment: so finally it's working. haaa

Comment: Now I have another error! The app works fine in the emulator, but not in the physical device! I only take the .apk from bin folder and put it on the phone. The app crashes when it starts. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following,

```
< meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" > 
< /meta-data>
```

in your manifest file immediately below the first meta-data tag(where you have placed your google api key)

Comment: Thank you, I will appreciate it forever sir.

Comment: Now I have another error! The app works fine in the emulator, but not in the physical device! I only take the .apk from bin folder and put it on the phone. The app crashes when it starts. Any thought?

Comment: Which version of android device are you using??

Comment: 4.2.2, the same than the emulator i think (Google API 17). It is rooted with a rom (Cyanogen). I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: ok.then debug your application.I guess you will able to identify the exception then.

Comment: I don't find nothing! Really, this is getting me crazy. It's incredible, it works on the emulator, but not on the device! And both are the same.