# Google Maps API v2 does NOT works on Emulator, but NOT on Device

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-maps, api-key

Thanks to the community I could solve my last problem. **This** --->([Google Maps API v2 - Fragment's error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152882/google-maps-api-v2-fragments-error))

The app works on the emulator (it shows the "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services), something normal, but when I put the .apk on the phone (4.2.2 version), it crashs!

I read somehting about different API keys. Now in my proyect, I have the API Key i got from the program (with the SHA1 fingerprint from Eclipse).

Do I need maybe a different one?

Thank you, and sorry for these two consecutive questions!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another key. You just need a good emulator to run Google Maps. I am using GenyMotion. It is really fast & efficient. Give it a try.

Follow The Steps

1)Install the Oracle VirtualBox Latest version.

2)Install the geneymotion latest version.

3)Download following Apps,

```
www.dropbox.com/s/lfde3juixuy88rg/GoogleLoginService.apk
www.dropbox.com/s/9kurwyhbbuecaea/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
www.dropbox.com/s/9x8924gtb52ksn6/Phonesky.apk
www.dropbox.com/s/koo4wiwqg8agy8n/com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk
www.dropbox.com/s/bh058hbrelccfsr/com.google.android.gms-2.apk
```

4)Run the Genymotion & install the device version,

5)Drag & Drop these app to Genymotion.

6)Restart the Genymotion.

7)Your genymotion is ready to run the Google Maps,