# Android : Top level element is not completed in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem when i'm trying to use Google Play Services in my app.
I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start but i have an error after i put this line into my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

On the android:name line, error is : "Top level element is not completed, Valid XML document must have a root tag". But, my XML file is valid without the meta-data line.

My AndroidManifest.xml starts like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.objectifmultimedia.chasseursbn">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TutorielActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutoriel" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementActualitesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_actualites" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementPermisDeChasserActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_permis_de_chasser" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementDatesOuverturesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_dates_ouvertures" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementEspacePersonnelActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_espace_personnel" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementAnnuairesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_annuaires" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementMeteoEphemerideActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_meteo_ephemeride" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementCommunesLimitrophesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_communes_limitrophes" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Aide.AideActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_aide" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PendantMaChasse.PendantMaChasseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pendant_ma_chasse" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementActualitesDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_actualites_detail" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Departements.DepartementDatesOuverturesDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_departement_dates_ouvertures_detail" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PendantMaChasse.PendantMaChasseMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pendant_ma_chasse_map"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PendantMaChasse.PendantMaChasseDatesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pendant_ma_chasse_dates" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.
Yann

Comment: where exactly do you add it in manifest?

Comment: The error is telling that your `meta-tag` is missing the parent tag enclosing it. Maybe your forgot to define the parent tag?

Comment: I just add my file into my post. ;)

Comment: check if this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest

Comment: add complete Manifest file.

Comment: @AlexanderZhak I saw that post. But my problem is not really here. My android:value line looks like ok. Maybe it's more an XML problem ...

Comment: I don't really understand why but it just work ... no more action ... Thx everyone.

Answer (score 21):

## 3 easy steps:

1. Select element in `xml` that displays error.
2. Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> on the drawable item which calls error (for example: `"@drawable/example"`).
3. And select **"Uninject language/reference"**

hope this might help

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file is correct.
 try to things here.

1) Add required library into your project. If done!!

2) Clean(Go to Project Menubar > Click on Clean > Select project > Done) your project. This should solve your problem

Comment: I did it, but message is still there. I forgot to say that i'm on Android Studio. May it be a bug from the beta version ? Btw, app is lunching correctly on my device ... I don't understand why ...

Answer (score 0):

Stupid error in my case Xml tag of sub parent is closed like this
`<Tag />`
instead of
`<Tag> Some more tags </Tag>`