# cant resolve symbol for google play services in android manifest

Tags: java, android

I was following this tutorial on how to get AdMob on your app: [Tutorial here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

on the part where it tells you what to put in your AndroidManifest file, where it says

```
 <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In my project in android studio whenever I try to write this in my android manifest the value `"@integer/google_play_services_version"` comes as cant resolve symbol. How do i fix this.

I have installed Google play services, Google repository and Android support Repository and library in the sdk. Im using android studio not eclipse too.

Comment: I think you question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure to update the build.gradle file with

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'

and to rebuild/clean the project?

Make sure you're not working offline and you have a good Internet connection (the gradle needs to be able to access the Internet)