# Google Map V2 in android phone not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am facing problem in a android Google map v2 based application
I ran in my phone [ Android OS, v4.2.2 (Jelly Bean) ] but error occurs.
I am giving my source code below with Logcat.
My phone is in Wi-Fi connected but i think the problem is in Google-Map
Please Help! Thanks in Advance!

Logcat:

```
11-21 06:40:50.672: D/jdwp(7984): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x45
11-21 06:40:50.676: W/asset(7984): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
11-21 06:40:50.740: D/AndroidRuntime(7984): Shutting down VM
11-21 06:40:50.741: W/dalvikvm(7984): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d8b9a8)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.example.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     ... 11 more
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.E(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.T(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.S(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.mA(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4734)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-21 06:40:50.755: E/AndroidRuntime(7984):     ... 21 more
11-21 06:40:53.425: I/Process(7984): Sending signal. PID: 7984 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_xml File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIfdsfsql6casdfsdfsdf9XTwcWe-sdfEAsdfGg" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what the error message is telling you to do and add the following tag to your AndroidManifest.xml within the `<application>` element.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also see this question and answer if you run into trouble when trying that:

[Adding Google Play services version to your app's manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest)