# Google map isnt loading on android app, blank screen appears when app is run

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Please find below code.

Manifest.xml --added all required permissions and API key

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.achra.fmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.achra.fma.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.achra.fmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.achra.fmap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.achra.fmap.Activity_map"/>
        <activity android:name=".FMap" 
                   android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="removed key intentionally" />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

map_view.xml --layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_Map.java

```
    package com.achra.fmap;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

    public class Activity_map extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    }
```

We could see map grid on screen but map doesn't appear.
Please guide further.

We are using Google Maps API v2.

Comment: try changing the `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing `com.google.android.gms.version` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

If you look at your logs you will probably see this:

```
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Try adding it just below your API key:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="removed key intentionally" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: On adding "com.google.android.gms.version" to Manifest.xml, we are getting below error on line "@integer/google_play_services_version"
-> No resource found that matchesthe given name.

We did import package google-play-services_lib in workspace.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv

Comment: @Achra This answer might help too.  If all else fails, do Project->clean a couple of times.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest/22648826#22648826

Comment: @Achra are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Hi, I am using Eclipse.

Comment: now I a gettig the following errors in Logs and my application force closes .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77449/discussion-between-achra-and-daniel-nugent).