# android studio 1.5.1 auto add google play services

Tags: android, android-studio

I just install android studio 1.5.1 it was works fine but now i give this error message

```
  Error:(63, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I do not use google play services but seems android studio add it automatically.

In my **AndroidManifest** this line auto generate

```
 <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and when i delete it ,that's com back again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest

Comment: using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

Comment: but i do not need google play services

Comment: Try to check your settings when you create a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by  @IntelliJ Amiya hint i add google play service library and error gone.
but steel i do not know why android studio add this
`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
lines automatically to my manifist.