# Adding meta tag in manifest.xml file for admob

Tags: android, xml, admob, android-manifest

I am trying to add meta tag to add admob to my application but it is giving me error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.deepak.indoreinfo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.deepak.indoreinfo.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"                                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

It is giving me error **No resources found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')** but this value is available in library project

Comment: The statement is ok. Are you sure you've imported `google_play-lib` correctly?

Comment: Make sure you have added the google play library correctly? Also try to restart your eclipse/android studio

Comment: i think i have added play library correctly....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play Services Library update and missing symbol @integer/google\_play\_services\_version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv)