# Version.xml is missing from googleplayservicesfryo in library project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

- I just updated the googlePlayServices in mySDK
- When i link it into my project i get a error message

---

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/
 google_play_services_version').
```

---

**What i tried**::

- cleaning the project
- Changing workspace

---

Then i found out that `version.xml` is not present in my GooglePlayServices

---

Below is a file from my old playservices of `version.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">4323000</integer>
</resources>
```

---

**My Question**::

- What should i need to add for the playservices Fryo and & resolve my
  error
- I just need the proper version number for version.xml, with that i can resolve my
  error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play services for Froyo does not export it. Just remove

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

from your manifest.

Comment: I have added those lines in manifest  android:value line is giving this error ... error is something related to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045696/1083093 ..... please can you go to folder of googleplayservices in your pc and check the version.xml from res/values and post the xml here ...hope i am clear

Comment: You do not copy anything from Google Play services library.

Comment: android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" .... refers to a version.xml file in res/values in library project ..... which is missing from the package i downloaded ... I am sure knowing the version number can resolve this issue

Comment: As per my answer - you just remove `com.google.android.gms.version` from your Manifest and that's should be it. You do not need it.

Comment: What error for a God sake? It does NOT exist for Froyo version. Remove entry from manifest and that's it. Your app will work as Froyo version of the lib does not check for that `meta-data`.