# Cannot setup Google Play services in Android Studio 0.5.9

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.9 on OS X. I'm attempting to get the Google APIs to work using the instructions here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install

However, when I get to the part about adding this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml, it says that it "Cannot resolve @integer/google_play_services_version", and it won't let me import anything starting with "com.google".

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
}
```

I'm completely stumped!
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using? Directly or through the wrapper?

Comment: Not sure. I'm kind of new to this. However, when I navigate to ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists it has gradle-1.12-bin. How can I find out if it's through the wrapper or not?

Comment: Okay so it had to do with the module not being added as a dependency:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19844573/1955559

Answer (score 0):

There must have been some issue caused by upgrading Android Studio. I found a solution to the issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19844573/1955559

Answer (score 0):

Installing Google Repository from Extras in SDK Manager was solution for me