# How can I compile the older version of google play service in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I had tried the new version(8.4.0) of google play service in my application. This had successful to run.
But I want to compile the older google play service.
When I change the version in Android Studio, it cannot sync successful.
How can I compile the correct older google play service. I want to compile version at lease 6.0.5. 
Thank you!

Here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tina.releasemap"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that "it cannot sync successful"? Maybe you're choosing a version that does not exist? Please paste the actual dependency line

Comment: I had updated the questions which had the build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select just a random version of `play-services` and hope it'll work. The only versions you can select from are the ones you've installed through Android SDK Manager inside your IDE.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

**To check which versions you have, you need to check your SDK dir. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548522/1993204).**