# Android: Old Google Drive integration issue?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

My Android application integrates with Google Drive using the API Google published prior it's current Drive API, it includes a bunch of jars like 'google-api-client-1.12.0-beta.jar', 'google-api-services-drive-v2-rev59-1.12.0-beta.jar', etc...

And in my manifest file, I include:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I'm not sure what changed, but this line in my manifest file now gives the following error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value 
 '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I see that I could use the new google-play-services_lib to resolve this error, but this would require rewriting my entire integration to use the new api. Is there any way to reference the resource value @integer/google_play_services_version without including the new library project? (Or any idea how my project previously compiled without this error, despite not defining this resource or including a lib project that did?)

It works if I set the value to "6587000", which is the value I found in the library project. But I can't imagine this is a good idea, I would think it would be device/version specific?

Comment: **"...but this would require rewriting my entire integration to use the new api."** : I haven't done anything with Google Drive but, as with most Google Beta API stuff, I'd be surprised if the old documentation didn't have a warning along the lines of "Warning this API is liable to change in future - do not use for release versions of apps blah blah". This is not uncommon and the long and short of it is you really ought to rewrite to use the new API - failure to do so is just likely to cause you more problems in the future. It's the price you pay for being an early adopter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what Environment you are developing on, you'll find the fixes to a similar problem over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv). However, even if it does help you I would suggest to upgrade the Drive version to v2. Generally such problems occur when older versions get deprecated and their endpoints have stopped working.