# Android studio dont see GoogleApiClient intance

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

I have added following dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

I have these 2 lines in Manifest file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But, @integer/google_play_services_version is not resolved. I tried to put import that I found in an other question but "common" library doesn't exist. I have downloaded Google Play Services from SDK. What did I do wrong and what I should do to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you rebuilt your program after adding the entries to your build.gradle file?

Comment: Check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv

Comment: FYI, you don't have to put this in your manifest anymore if you don't import all of GooglePlayServices (which you shouldn't), see here: https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/8ewDRqGUFyp

Comment: Also, you should make sure that your support-design and appcompat library versions match up....

Comment: of course I rebuilt program,but nothing happen

Comment: Does your project compile if you take out that entry from the manifest?

Comment: yes,its compile.Oh.It works!Thank you!