# Eclipse - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I ran my app code source on Eclipse today after changing computers, and I got this error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version'

I have tried many solutions, but it's not working. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you tell us what you were trying to run (with some source code preferably)? Also if you don't want to be downvoted, you should probably remove the "PLEASE HELP ME" and "And i don t know what to", along with the the last 2 blockquotes, and put your error in the question, not title. You should also include what you have attempted and how that has worked,,,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Services Library update and missing symbol @integer/google\_play\_services\_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv)